# fwrite different following fread in a tcpip connection? [matlab]

Tags: matlab, tcp

In the process of writing a class to connect 2 instances of matlab together. the instances will be on separate computers but I'm currently testing on 1 computer.

Currently I'm able to establish a connection between both matlabs and I'm able to send/receive messages between them.

code:

```
classdef connectcompstogether<handle
    properties
        serverIP
        clientIP
        tcpipServer
        tcpipClient
        Port = 4000;
        bsize = 8;
        Message
    end

    methods
        function gh = connectcompstogether(~)
            % gh.serverIP = '127.0.0.1';
            gh.serverIP = 'localhost';
            gh.clientIP = '0.0.0.0';
        end

        function SetupServer(gh)
            gh.tcpipServer = tcpip(gh.clientIP,gh.Port,'NetworkRole','Server');
            set(gh.tcpipServer,'OutputBufferSize',gh.bsize);
            fopen(gh.tcpipServer);
            display('Established Connection')
        end

        function SetupClient(gh)
            gh.tcpipClient = tcpip(gh.serverIP,gh.Port,'NetworkRole','Client');
            set(gh.tcpipClient,'InputBufferSize',gh.bsize);
            set(gh.tcpipClient,'Timeout',30);
            fopen(gh.tcpipClient);
            display('Established Connection')
        end
        function CloseClient(gh)
            fclose(gh.tcpipClient);
        end
    end
    methods
        function sendmessage(gh,message)
            fwrite(gh.tcpipServer,message,'double');
        end

        function recmessage(gh)
            gh.Message = fread(gh.tcpipClient,gh.bsize);
        end
    end
end
```

matlab 1

```
gh = connectcompstogether;
gh.SetupServer();
gh.sendmessage(555);
```

matlab 2

```
gh = connectcompstogether;
gh.SetupClient();
gh.recmessage();
```

the message sent is an 8 bit double **555**.
However when looking at the received message it turns out to be a matrix

```
64
129
88
```

don't understand what is going on as the [examples](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2011/05/27/transferring-data-between-two-computers-using-matlab/) I have been following don't have this problem.

and to add context. I'm trying to connect 2 matlabs through TCP-IP so I can control one instance with another. my plan is to have a second matlab waiting for command codes and execute specified functions when the 1st matlab requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*tcpip/fread* default precision is *uchar*, so by default *fread* will output a column array of 8-bit unsigned integers.

You either need to specifiy that a double is expected:

```
%size divided by 8, as one 8-byte value is expected rather than 8 1-byte values
gh.Message = fread(gh.tcpipClient,gh.bsize/8,'double');
```

Or *typecast* the uint8 array to a double:

```
rawMessage = fread(gh.tcpipClient,gh.bsize); %implicit: rawMessage is read in 'uchar' format 
% cast rawMessage as uint8 (so that each value is stored on a single byte in memory, cancel MATLAB automatic cast to double)
% then typecast to double (tell MATLAB to re-interpret the bytes in memory as double-precision floats)
% a byteswap is necessary as bytes are sent in big-endian order while native endianness for most machines is little-endian
gh.Message = swapbytes(typecast(uint8(rawMessage),'double'));
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. That explains why I'm receiving an array. The first example given fixed the problem. I tried the second though and typecast appeared to not have an affect on the rawMessage. any reason why?

Comment: Perhaps Matlab reads the input as bytes, then casts it as double (i.e. outputs an array of double precision floats with integer values in the 0-255 range). So, `rawMessage` should be manually cast as uint8. I will edit the answer.